# Deleted Owners rights and alerts for group members

Tags: user-accounts

Old accounts were removed from AD and one of the accounts was the owner of some dokuments in Sharepoint. Now that the owner has been removed, the cases and subsites/documents are not displayed correctly. Does anyone know how to change owner who do not exist anymore in sharepoint and how to create alert for members to know that a particular member/owner has been deleted or inactive in the company sharepoint server?